# Is it dangerous to have these electrical cables on top of shower?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, shower, ceiling

Remodeling old apartment, the bathroom has electrical cables running through a low ceiling, that we pulled down. There is a remaining part of the low ceiling that we left and can't take down and that's where we routed the electrical cables right under it. Below it is supposed to be the shower.

I was told it would be difficult to move these cables to the wall without crossing the ceiling. That low ceiling or divider in picture below is supposed to be covered in ceramic so the cables will not be exposed. The orange tubes carry cables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What country?  And are you sure those are mains electrical cables?  Not an issue for phone or cable TV.

Comment: It's mains im sure. Not phone. Country Egypt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. The cables themselves have one or more layers of unbroken, waterproof insulation.
2. The orange conduit is itself unbroken.
3. The orange conduit will be covered with a surface impermeable to water and steam before any water is present.

> Is it dangerous to have these electrical cables on top of shower?

No.  It is not the slightest bit dangerous.

Aesthetically and functionally it would be nicer to have the wires, and that beam, out of the way to have a more open shower.  But the electrical safety is not a problem at all.

Comment: They told me the beam is structural and extends all way through the apartment. I want to remove it but looks like I can't. So I will cover it with dark tiles to make it seem delibrate. It will sit between white painted ceiling. Unless you think it's better to have tiled ceiling directly above the shower? The problem either way is ventilation, where it could trap the steam.

Comment: Tile for all surfaces of the shower makes sense.  You should use an exhaust fan to manage steam.

Comment: Won't it look odd having tiles on ceilings? I never seen it before. Unfortunately I can't have fan there either inly by the window far from shower.

Comment: I think the tiled ceiling of my shower is AWESOME! I'll add a photo of it to my answer.  Just imagine how gross a shower ceiling would be if it was just drywall, or some other non-water-safe material, and it got wet and started molding over.

Comment: Actualy, I don't think the answer is the right place for photos of a tile ceiling shower, but here they are https://goo.gl/3QRzMj  https://goo.gl/S2g4mo . Use large tiles to make the work easy on yourself and reduce the total number of lines that could end up crooked.  Pick something with a neutral pattern because you're going to have to live with it for a long time, and avoid strong colors which could otherwise hurt the eyes that close and all around.

Comment: I tried seeing if it would work but unfortunately the tiles I already have arnt appropriate for ceilings. Have to think of something else or just leave it. I'm wondering whether I should just lower the ceiling in that area and live with not being able to raise my arms in shower, as a possibility.

Comment: Also is it easy to have spotlights on tiles?

Comment: I don't know about easy.  With large tiles it means cutting a curve in them.  To do that probably takes a special bit, a lot of patience, and some spare tiles. A lot of showers get their light from else where in the room.  If I was designing it, I would use low voltage DC lighting and run the (smaller) DC wires between tiles while the grout was still wet.